# Create Menu Items and Navigation Groups in LightSwitch web

Tags: lightswitch-2013

I found navigation group for DesktopClient in

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff851994.aspx

Can any one show me its we equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no equivalent of these groups on the HTML client, you can only add and remove screens.

If you would like a kind of grouping functionality, I'd suggest you take a look at Michael Washington's push menu sample (http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/3247/Visual-Studio-LightSwitch-HTML-Client-Push-Menu.aspx).

Comment: The drop down from screen title is the place where the menu items appear although they cannot be dynamically controlled just removed